# Read/export HTTP requests from a Javascript-activated browser?

Tags: javascript, http, firefox-addon, xss

I want to test my website for certain vulnerabilities.

I'd like to read the HTTP requests send to the browser over a session and send them to another program in real time.
This way I can modify them and/or send my own malicious requests to the server.

Is there a way to do this?

I assume I could set up an SSL MITM locally, filter and sniff traffic with TCPDUMP, then feed the requests to my program as parameters, and then use cURL to reply, but this sounds like too much work.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: ZAP Proxy? Burp Suite? Fiddler?

Comment: @GaborLengyel ZAP Proxy was neat and the replace function covered my immediate need, but it doesn't seem to have a way to export/import the HTTP requests so I can write scripts ie in Python.